# Tezos Taquito Originating

Tags: taquito

In taquito What is the web service being called with what data and end point while originating?
I couldn't figure it out, can you please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint for all operation types is the same. All operations go to `https://<node-rpc-address>/injection/operation`, with a different payload for each type.

If you are looking for help crafting the Taquito payload you can see examples on the taquito docs: https://tezostaquito.io/docs/originate

If you are looking to understand the RPC schema, you can check the openAPI spec for the simulation RPC, which lists all the possible operation types. Go here: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/docs/api/hangzhou-openapi.json and scroll down to `helpers/scripts/run_operation`. Expand it and expand the schema:

[image]

There are also some other protocol specific OPEnAPi's if you are interested, the root link to all of them is here: https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/openapi.html

Comment: Thank You so much for helping me. :D

Comment: @Cerealkiller your welcome. If this solved your question, don't forget to mark this answer as the accepted answer to close the question